# Motorcycle fairing or motorcycle cowling?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these two when used within the context of a motorcycle?

> "**Fairing**" and "**Cowling**".

Is it a British-English / American-English distinction?

An image search on Google brings up the same pictures. Although, the use of fairings in "normal" web search, returns the best result.

"Cowling" would be the direct equivalent to the word in my own language.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. While we can provide an answer here, questions about specialized terminology may be answered more authoritatively at one of our sister sites in the subject, such as [Mechanics.SE].

Comment: I suspect this is an undecided lexical argument even among native speakers, although only an enthusiast would care whether you belong to the *cowling* tribe or the *fairing* tribe  :)

Comment: I don't think there's much difference, but from what I can tell from a few web searches, *fairing* is much more common than *cowling*.

Comment: I've owned motorcycles for twenty years in the US, and I've never heard the term "cowling." I have a motorcycle with a fairing, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fairing** and **cowling** are not the same thing. A cowling is a covering for an engine, usually referring to an airplane engine. A cowling is meant to be protective and aerodynamic.

A fairing is a plastic shell that goes on the front of a motorcycle to reduce drag and to protect the rider from wind and other things like flying pebbles and insects. It so happens that a fairing usually covers the engine, too, so it is, in a way, a cowling. But motorcycle riders use the term "fairing," not "cowling."

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cowling

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorcycle_fairing

Comment: Yamaha on their website use the term cowling for, in this case, a full cowl that fits with the standard upper fairing of the motorcycle. This is what confuses me. It seems like the cowl is something you attach the fairing in this case. But a search for a full fairing, will bring results picturing motorcycles with full fairing looking like this cowl. https://www.yamaha-motor.eu/uk/accessories/genuine-options/functional/fz1-fazer-full-cowling/3C3-W0712-63-10/details.acc

Comment: Here's a better photo of the same part. You can see that it covers the engine. It also happens to protect the lower body and attaches to the "upper fairing," which is the windshield and protection for arms. I still think cowling is a term meant just for engines. http://www.racewaysmotorcycles.co.uk/buy/Yamaha-FZ1-Fazer-Full-Cowling/tzr3c3w07129100fz1f.htm

Comment: Because it covers the engine AND protects the rider, it can be called either a cowling or a lower fairing. For whatever reason, Yamaha decided to call it a cowling. I wouldn't get too concerned about why it's called cowling instead of fairing. It could have been a marketing decision. But fairing is the term motorcycle riders generally use.

Answer (score 0):

A Cowling primarily covers the engine and its immediate parts and may become part of a nacelle assembly. It is primarily to protect, promote cooling and add some better aerodynamics than a bare engine. A fairing is also a specially shaped piece used primarily to promote aerodynamics, but could take many shapes and be very small or large and could appear anywhere on an airplane (or motorcycle).

A fairing is placed on the machine in a place where the machine has a sharp angle or protuberance into the airstream causing undesirable drag in order to smooth that area. A typical airplane may have a cowl covering the engine up front and a fairing where the wing joins the fuselage, where the nav lights stick out, there is a little ridge about once inch high; that is the nav light fairing. The antenna mount is covered in a smooth teardrop shaped donut fairing. The wheel pants defy explanation, and are neither fairing, nor cowls but could be referred to as shrouds or even nacelles? To compound the denotation, all these pieces and even the whole aerodynamic airplane could be referred to as fully faired. A loose and inconcise use of the word 'fairing' could apply to almost any part of the skin of a modern airplane. Calling things by their precise name is always more concise.

The front forks, fender, headlight handlebars, front wheel, mirrors, turn indicators...all hanging out in the wind are definitely causing bad drag and turbulence, so a fairing is made to cover the projections.

If you put an aerodynamic belly pan on the engine, and lower fairings that partially enclose the engine, perhaps with a radiator shroud that blends into the upper fairing, then that is very close to what I would call a cowl around the engine on many large touring machines today. Some of which have completely hidden engines. Is a tailcone on a bike a fairing or a nacelle? I would say, yes. Certain parts of airplanes have unusual names, like pitot tube and ruddervator.

In this case, it is my humble and unworthy opinion that a motorcycle could have both a fairing and a cowl at the same time or indeed, a fairing/cowl combination, depending on the design.

A helmet is sort of a cowl, and some of them are faired. Some airplanes have cowls as part of the canopy.This is the realm of the technical writers at Boeing.

Comment: Hello John. Welcome to ELL. This mostly repeats what was already written eight years ago.  I suggest you look for newer or unanswered questions, as this will be more useful.